# How to execute ubuntu shell command in C# to get exitCode as 0

Tags: c#, ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu Shell command through C# code, when I run this Script in Ubuntu it shows as 'Syntax OK' but when I run it through C# code it Always returns exitCode - 1. Please Correct my code if something id wrong.

```
            string _exitCode="";
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash"; 

            proc.StartInfo.Arguments ="-c \" apachectl -t -f /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.conf \""; 

            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

            proc.Start();

            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

            proc.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();

            proc.WaitForExit(3000);

            if (!proc.HasExited)
                proc.Kill();

            _exitCode = proc.ExitCode.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

to correct command :

```
"-c \"/etc/init.d/apachectl -t -f /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.conf 2>&1\"";
```